# How to set KEYGUARD_DISABLE_TRUST_AGENTS flag

Tags: android, android-source

I use this function:

```
int ret = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService((String)"device_policy")).getKeyguardDisabledFeatures(null)
```

and i want it return 16 , but it actually returns 0 . According to Google Docs, I found this Flag:

```
KEYGUARD_DISABLE_TRUST_AGENTS, which affects the parent user, but only if there is no separate challenge set on the managed profile.
```

So , i try my beast to set it on , like this :

```
1. Swipe down from the top of the screen once using two fingers, or twice using one finger
2. Security > Trust agents
3. Turn off the Smart Lock (Google) switch
```

But the function `getKeyguardDisabledFeatures` still return 0.
So , i really want to know how to make it return 16.